# C2084 error when calling function in same file in a diffrent function

Tags: c++, combinatorics

So, I'm trying to make a combinatorics library in a .h file. I have a function that calculates the factorial of a number n, followed by a function (in the same file) that uses the factorial function to calculate the combination of n choose k for a given n and k. But when I try to compile the code it throws this error at me: C2048 function 'long factorial(int)' already has a body. (I'm using VS 2015)

Here's the code:

```
long int factorial(int n) // factorial of n
{
    int summation = n;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        summation *= i;
    }

    return summation;
}

double combination(int n, int k) // n choose k
{
    return (factorial(n) / (factorial(k) * factorial(n - k)));
}

double permutation(int n, int k) // n permutation k
{
    if (k != n)
        return (factorial(n) / factorial(n - k));
    else
        return factorial(n);
}

double repetitiveCombination(int n, int k) // repetitive combination of n choose k
{
    return combination(n - 1 + k, k);
}

double orderEquals(int n, int p) // order n objects of wich p are equal
{
    return (factorial(n) / factorial(p));
}
```

Comment: Could not reproduce. Did you try creating a [mcve] yet?

Comment: There are a couple of things that are *probably* causing this. But don't make us guess. That's not a productive way to ask a question. How are you using this code? Is it in a header file or a code file? Are you #including it? If so, how and where? Like that other guy said, a minimum example that reproduces the problem would be a good start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably you don't have header guards. Your header should look like this:

```
#ifndef MYHEADERNAME_H
#define MYHEADERNAME_H
// Your code is here
#endif //end of MYHEADERNAME_H
```

[Wikipedia info here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard)

Comment: No, most probably missing header guards don't have to with the problem.

Comment: thanks that fixed the problem!

Answer (score 0):

This code you presented (or part of it) is in header, and you are including the header in two CPP files hence the error. Or, by mistake the implementation of `factorial` is landed into two source files. Look carefully.

Answer (score 0):

> So, I'm trying to make a combinatorics library in a .h file.

If you put non class member implementations into a header file, you need to prefix your functions with the `inline` keyword e.g.:

```
   inline long int factorial(int n) // factorial of n
// ^^^^^^
   {
        int summation = n;
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
        {
            summation *= i;
        }
        return summation;
  }
```

---

Also it would be good habit to put all your functions into their own namespace.